# QR Code resolves to .htm instead of .html, need 1 page to do the same

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

I've got a client with a monthly print publication and an online representation of said print publication. They generate their own QR Codes that go out in this publication and normally have the links associated with these codes end with .html. There was a typo when generating the QR Code and the URL associated with the QR ends with .htm instead. I've got MODx Revo set so that friendly URLs are ON and end with .html. How can I get this one single page to display with .htm instead of .html? (and I can't change the entire site to use .htm since many other existent QR's would break)

What I've tried: I copied the source of the page out and saved it in the root directory with the .htm extension instead of .html but of course index.php is controlling the site and it doesn't grab the 'hard coded' copy..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. Downloaded Redirector Package and 301 redirected it... I overthought that one from the beginning. Oops.